# Need loading GIF or progress bar while navigating from one page to another

Tags: c#, wpf

First page

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Page1 p1 = new Page1();
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(p1);

    }
```

Second Page(Page 1 as specified in the code )

```
        public Page1()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
```

get loading icon or progress bar while navigating from page 3 to page 1 on button click.

As soon as the user clicks on the button on page 3 this page hangs until page 1 processes the data in the background

Code will be preferable

Answer (score -1):

i have found this example at [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/515081/howplustoplussetplusprogressplusbarplusduringpluso) you give a look to the example. I hope this is help
How to set progress bar during one page to another page load in c# .net windows application?

```
This gets asked almost daily so I've written this short demonstration code to demonstrate how to use a System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker in combination with a System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar. All the code is commented so the flow/steps should be easy to understand.

Just drop a ProgressBar (progressBar1) and a BackgroundWorker (backgroundWorker1) onto your form and copy and paste this code to see it in action.
Hide   Shrink    Copy Code
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Shown += new EventHandler(Form1_Shown);

    // To report progress from the background worker we need to set this 
  property
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    // This event will be raised on the worker thread when the worker starts
    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
    // This event will be raised when we call ReportProgress
    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
}
void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Start the background worker
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
// On worker thread so do our thing!
void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Your background task goes here
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        // Report progress to 'UI' thread
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        // Simulate long task
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
// Back on the 'UI' thread so we can update the progress bar
void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // The progress percentage is a property of e
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
}
```

Comment: Hello there, as you have posted an answer which references an external link, i would suggest to edit the answer and post the codes along with it (because links can die). Also it would be easier for the OP itself to see the answer quickly! Else, you can refer links in comments(you'll unlock the ability to _comment_ after 50+ repo) :)